# Gaussian fit to histogram turns out to be a flat line

Tags: python, normalization, gaussian

```
from sklearn.mixture import GaussianMixture
from sklearn import preprocessing
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
from scipy import stats
from astropy.io import ascii
from scipy.stats import norm




data= pd.read_csv("P, Theta all stars.csv",usecols=[1])
names = data.columns

df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=names)
df.head()

mu,std=norm.fit(df)

x=df['Theta']

num_bins = 20

n, bins, patches = plt.hist(x, num_bins,  color ='green',alpha = 0.7)
   

p = norm.pdf(bins, mu, std)

plt.gcf().set_size_inches((10, 8))  
plt.plot(bins, p, '--', color ='black')
  

  

  



plt.title("Mean: {:.3f}  and  Standard Deviation: {:.3f}".format(mu, std))

plt.xlabel('Theta(curve fit)')
#plt.savefig("{0}.png", dpi=300)
plt.show()
```

[Gaussian Fit with density parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jvDAN.png)

[Gaussian Fit with no Density parameter](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TeIJ8.png)

I intend to have a gaussian fit while keeping the original y axis without normalising it . But if I want that, the gaussian is getting flattened (because the data is not normalised). In short how can I make both the data and the gaussian to be unnormalised?

Comment: There's nothing in your Python code that shows a "density" parameter being used. Judging from your figures, I'm guessing that the picture of "Gaussian Fit with density parameter" has a histogram generated from `plt.hist(..., density = True)` while the picture of "Gaussian fit with no density parameter" has a histogram generated from `plt.hist()` without the `density` argument being set. Am I correct?

Comment: @jjramsey Oops yes that is correct. My bad

Comment: There's nothing wrong with showing a histogram normalized so that the area underneath it is 1. Indeed, if you are going to compare the results of a histogram to a probability density distribution, that's the best way to do it, since a normalized histogram is an approximation to a probability distribution.